# Order of the number of solution to the equation $\phi(x) = n$

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

What is the asymptotic order (in terms of $n$) of the number of solution to the equations $\phi(x) = n$, where $x$ can be any integer and $n$ is given?

For example the solutions to $phi(x) = 36$ are $37, 57, 63, 74, 76, 108, 114, 126$.

Comment: There is no good asymptotic, as the function is "oscillating" (e.g. there is no solution for odd $n>1$). But you can write the asymptotic for mean number of solutions quite easily (by double counting).

Comment: @zhoraster, could you clearly state what do you mean exactly by mean number of solutions? Does it mean order of $\sum{\text{number of solutions to} \phi(x) = n}$?

Comment: Possibly helpful. http://oeis.org/A014197

Comment: I mean that, denoting by $s(n)$ the number of solutions to $\phi(x) = n$, it is possible to identify the asymptotics of $\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n s(k)$.